# React.renderToStaticMarkup outputs hexadecimal code

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm using `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` to render some html code onto a static webpage in a code block format.

Here's a close approximation of what my code looks like:

```
import { html_beautify } from 'js-beautify';
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';

...

render() {
    const snippet = html_beautify(renderToStaticMarkup(
        <div>
            <script>
                generateWidget(&#123;
                    buttonSize: 'BUTTON_SIZE',
                    elementID: 'ELEMENT_TO_INJECT_THE_WIDGET_INTO',
                    userID: 'ID_OF_USER'
                &#125;);
            </script>
        </div>
    ));
    return (
        <pre>
            <code>
                {snippet}
            </code>
        </pre>
    );
}
```

I was getting parsing errors from the JSX parser before I used the escape codes for `{` and `}`, so that's why those are present in the `render` function.

My issue is that `renderToStaticMarkup` replaces the single quotes in the code snippet with their corresponding hexadecimal codes. The output looks like this:

```
...
<script>
    karma.generateWidget({
        buttonSize: & #x27;BUTTON_SIZE & #x27;,
        elementID: & #x27;ELEMENT_TO_INJECT_THE_WIDGET_INTO & #x27;,
        userKarmaID: & #x27;KARMA_ID_OF_USER & #x27;
    });
</script>
```

Is there some way to get rid of the `& #x27;` hexadecimal codes being rendered by `renderToStaticMarkup` and have it render single quotes?

Note that if I replace the single quotes with double quotes, the `& #x27`'s are replaced with `& quot;`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React sanitizes HTML by default.

You will need to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html).